# How to edit a kubernetes secret using Rust?

Tags: kubernetes, rust, kubectl

I want to update a secret. It has a `data` field, the value of which needs to be updated. In Rust, I can use the APIs `create` and `delete` but there is no `update` or `edit`.

However, I can use `kubectl edit` command to edit an existing secret.

```
async fn create_k8s_secret(secrets: &Api<Secret>, secret: &Secret) -> bool {
    let secret_name = secret.metadata.name.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
    match secrets.create(&PostParams::default(), &secret).await {
        Ok(_) => {
            debug!("Successfully created secret: {}", secret_name);
            true
        }
        Err(kube::Error::Api(ErrorResponse { code, reason, .. }))
            if code == 409 && reason == "AlreadyExists" =>
        {
            debug!("Secret {} already exists. Ignoring...", secret_name);
            true
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Error creating secret {}: {}", secret_name, e);
            false
        }
    }
}

async fn delete_k8s_secret(secrets: &Api<Secret>, secret: &Secret) -> bool {
    let secret_name = secret.metadata.name.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
    let delete_options = kube::api::DeleteParams::default();
    match secrets.delete(&secret_name, &delete_options).await {
        Ok(_) => {
            debug!("Successfully deleted the secret: {}", secret_name);
            true
        }
        Err(kube::Error::Api(ErrorResponse { code, reason, .. }))
            if code == 404 && reason == "NotFound" =>
        {
            debug!("Secret {} does not exist. Ignoring...", secret_name);
            true
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Error deleting secret {}: {}", secret_name, e);
            false
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I can perform programmatically is to first delete the secret and then create a new one.

What is the most optimal and safe way to edit an existing `secret` in Kubernetes using Rust?

Comment: Are you sure `kubectl edit` doesn't just do the read+delete+create flow under the hood?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, I am not sure. Looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update your secret in place (without deleting/recreating) using [`patch`](https://docs.rs/kube/latest/kube/api/enum.Patch.html) method:

```rust
use k8s_openapi::api::core::v1::Secret;
use kube::{
    api::{Api, Patch, PatchParams},
    Client, Error,
};
use std::collections::HashMap;

async fn update_k8s_secret(
    secrets: &Api<Secret>,
    secret_namespace: String,
    secret_name: String,
    secret_data: HashMap<String, String>,
) -> bool {
    let patch_data = generate_patch_json(
        secret_namespace.clone(),
        secret_name.clone(),
        secret_data.clone(),
    );
    let patch = Patch::Apply(patch_data);
    let params = PatchParams::apply("kube");

    match secrets.patch(&secret_name, &params, &patch).await {
        Ok(_) => {
            println!("Successfully updated the secret: {}", secret_name);
            true
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error updating secret {}: {}", secret_name, e);
            false
        }
    }
}
```

For example, to update the data inside a secret `mysecret` in `default` namespace:

```rust
let client = Client::try_default().await?;
let secrets: Api<Secret> = Api::default_namespaced(client);

let secret_namespace = "default".to_string();
let secret_name = "mysecret".to_string();
let secret_data = HashMap::from([
    ("key1".to_string(), "value1".to_string()),
    ("key2".to_string(), "value2".to_string()),
]);

let updated = update_k8s_secret(&secrets, secret_namespace, secret_name, secret_data).await;
println!("Updated: {}", updated);
```

The `generate_patch_json` method used in `update_k8s_secret` aims to convert the secret namespace, name and data into a JSON object usable by `patch` method. For example:

```rust
let secret_namespace = "default".to_string();
let secret_name = "mysecret".to_string();
let secret_data = HashMap::from([
    ("key1".to_string(), "value1".to_string()),
    ("key2".to_string(), "value2".to_string()),
]);
generate_patch_json(secret_namespace, secret_name, secret_data);
```

Should return:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "mysecret",
    },
    "stringData": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

I'm far from being a Rust expert/user, so please bear with me, but I'll still put my implementation here. It is probably not optimal nor uses the best practices, but hey, this works!

```rust
fn generate_patch_json(
    secret_namespace: String,
    secret_name: String,
    secret_data: HashMap<String, String>,
) -> serde_json::Map<String, serde_json::Value> {
    let mut secret_data_map = serde_json::Map::new();
    for (key, value) in secret_data {
        secret_data_map.insert(key, value.into());
    }

    let mut metadata_map = serde_json::Map::new();
    metadata_map.insert("namespace".to_string(), secret_namespace.into());
    metadata_map.insert("name".to_string(), secret_name.clone().into());

    let mut patch_data = serde_json::Map::new();
    patch_data.insert("apiVersion".to_string(), "v1".into());
    patch_data.insert("kind".to_string(), "Secret".into());
    patch_data.insert(
        "metadata".to_string(),
        serde_json::Value::Object(metadata_map),
    );
    patch_data.insert(
        "stringData".to_string(),
        serde_json::Value::Object(secret_data_map),
    );

    patch_data
}
```